# VHDL "expecting type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR" when that is the type I'm giving

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

```
library IEEE;

use work.vec9Arr.all; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity vector_scalar_multiplier is
port(
    in_a : in vec9arr;
    in_b : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    out_vec : out vec9arr);
end vector_scalar_multiplier;

architecture structure of vector_adder is

component multiplier is
    generic (
        O_width : integer := 8;
        P_width : integer := 8
    );

    port (
        in_O : in std_logic_vector(O_width - 1 downto 0);
        in_P : in std_logic_vector(P_width - 1 downto 0);
        out_F : out std_logic_vector((O_width + P_width) - 1 downto 0)
    );
end component;



begin


GEN_MULT : for i in 0 to 8 generate
MULT : multiplier
    generic map(O_width => 16, P_width => 8)
    port map(
        in_O => in_b,
        in_P => in_a(i),
        out_F => out_vec(i));
end generate;

end structure;
```

A pretty simple entity that multiplies every element of a vector by a scalar. I get the following error upon compiling:

[image]

I've been looking for some syntax error that might cause this, but I must be missing something. What might cause an error like this?

I don't think this is cause by the custom vec9arr as I have another VHDL file in the same directory that also uses vec9arr and doesn't have any issues.

Comment: The problem can't be reproduced without a [mcve]. The accepted answer doesn't teach a solution noting the occurrence of in_b in architecture of vector_adder has no visible declaration (nor does it apparent type). Nor can pictures of error messages yield useful information by search for future Stackoverflow  readers.Your comment to the accepted answer sheds no light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity name is: `vector_scalar_multiplier`
But your architecture declaration is: `vector_adder`

Therefore the signals you are referencing in your architecture can only be the signals that are defined in the `vector_adder` entity declaration and any internal signals you define with the `signal` keyword (Of which I see none of in this example)

Did you intend to define an architecture for `vector_scalar_multiplier`? If not could you please include the entity declaration for `vector_adder`?

Comment: Yep. Just turns out I don't know how to read. Thank you so much!